# How to loop through databases to determine which log file to shrink?

Tags: sql-server

In my SQL instance I  have about 50 databases in simple recovery model.  At times there is lot of activity which cause the log files to balloon up and fill up the log drive.

I tried to write a script to execute once a day, to check for which log files are greater that 30 gb, and have 80% or more free space.  Only then I want to run the DBCC Shrinkfile.
However, I do not now how to put a  loop in the script to cycle through the databases and capture
the name and logfile name.

```
-- create result holder

DECLARE @result TABLE
    (
      [Database_Name] VARCHAR(150) ,
      [Log_Size] FLOAT ,
      [Log_Space] FLOAT ,
      [Status] VARCHAR(100)
    ) 
 
INSERT  INTO @result
        EXEC ( 'DBCC sqlperf(LOGSPACE) WITH NO_INFOMSGS'
            )
 
-- only return for the DB in context, rounding it 

Declare @SQL varchar(2000), @logsize float,@logspace float

SELECT  @logsize =Round(Log_Size,2), @logspace=100 - Log_space
FROM @result



If @logsize >= 30000 and @logspace >= 80  
set @SQL = 'use ' +'[NameofDatabase]'+' dbcc shrinkfile ([Enternameoflogfile], 20000, TRUNCATEONLY) WITH NO_INFOMSGS'

exec (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a `CURSOR`, but there is one problem with that - or any similar - approach. You cannot start a new `DBCC SHRINKFILE` operation while another one is still running. And I cannot think of a reliable way to get the loop to "wait" until the previous operation is completed. You could use `WAITFOR DELAY` and experiment with different time intervals, but it still wouldn't necessarily guarantee the statement had completed. Here is how I modified your code, with a 10 second delay.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @log_data TABLE
    (
      [Database_Name] sysname,
      [Log_Size] float,
      [Log_Space] float,
      [Status] varchar(100)
    );
 
INSERT INTO @log_data 
EXEC ('DBCC sqlperf(LOGSPACE) WITH NO_INFOMSGS');

DECLARE @result TABLE 
    (
      [Database_Name] sysname,
      [Log_Size] float,
      [Log_Free_Space] float,
      [Log_Name] sysname
    );

-- Get the log file names
INSERT INTO @result SELECT d.[name], l.[Log_Size], 100.0 - l.[Log_Space] AS [Log_Free_Space], f.[name]
FROM sys.databases d JOIN sys.master_files f ON d.database_id=f.database_id JOIN @log_data l ON d.[name] = l.[Database_Name]
WHERE d.database_id > 4 AND f.[type] = 1; -- id > 4 = no system dbs, type 1 = log file

DECLARE @db_name sysname;
DECLARE @log_file sysname;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [Database_Name], [Log_Name] FROM @result WHERE [Log_Size] >= 30000.0 AND [Log_Free_Space] >= 80.0
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name, @log_file
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'USE [' + @db_name + N']; DBCC SHRINKFILE ([' + @log_file + N'], 20000, TRUNCATEONLY) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;'
    EXEC (@sql)
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'; -- experiment with this value to get the correct delay

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name, @log_file -- get the next db_name and log file
  END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This script worked like a charm!   I'm very thankful for your assistance.

Comment: @veenaranganath you are welcome. Please mark my answer as the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

For the databases loop you can use **sp_MSForEachDB**.

For the sizes of the log files, you can use the following query:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SELECT
     [Database Name] = DB_NAME()
     ,[File Name] = F.[name]
     ,[Physical Name] = F.physical_name  
     ,[Total Size In MB] = CAST((F.size / 128.0) as decimal(15, 2))  
     ,[Available Space In MB] = CAST(F.size / 128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(F.[name], 'SpaceUsed') as int) / 128.0 as decimal(15, 2))  
     ,[Growth In MB] = CAST((F.Growth / 128.0) as decimal(15, 2))
     ,[Filegroup Name] = FG.[name] 
 FROM 
     sys.database_files F
     LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS FG ON FG.data_space_id = F.data_space_id
 WHERE
     F.data_space_id = 0 —Log File
 ORDER BY
   F.[name] 
 ASC
```